# Rails how to Gzip Javascript? (Heroku)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have run google page speed and it is saying that I should Gzip my javascript files?

How do I gzip my javascript files? My website is hosted on heroku if that mattter

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This answer is out of date but I can't delete it because it was accepted. So I'm turning it into a community wiki so that people can fix it up.

---

Heroku should be gzipping everything automatically (as long as the client supports it of course). From an [old blog post](http://adam.heroku.com/past/2009/4/22/gzip_makes_a_happy_web/):

> All apps deployed to Heroku automatically compress pages they serve, by virtue of passing through Nginx’s gzip filter on the way out.

And from [the current documentation](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing):

> On the heroku.com HTTP stack, requests enter the platform through Nginx, which handles SSL and Gzip.

Comment: This is no longer valid for the HerokuApp.com stack (notably: Celadon Cedar). Because requests are no longer run through a server like nginx, the application is responsible for compressing assets. http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#the_herokuappcom_http_stack

Comment: @Corey: Thanks for the update, it is still valid for the the heroky.com stacks, right?

Comment: Yes, it's still valid for Aspen and Bamboo (anything with a .heroku.com domain). Heroku tries not to change anything on existing stacks, hence the creation of new stacks.

Answer (score 4):

You can prezip your assets by using the jammit gem, running the jammit command before deploy, and uploading directly to heroku.  Just make an config/assets.yml file, and then run "jammit"

http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit/

Answer (score -2):

As far as I understand it's web server's task to gzip files, I doubt you can modify heroku settings.

Besides, javascript files are usually cached by a browser, so normally it is not what you should be concerned about.